# Pandas: Sort a Multiindex Dataframe's multi-level column with mixed datatypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is my dataframe:

```
In [2804]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'D':[{"value": '126', "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": 324, "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": 'N/A', "perc": None, "unit": None}, {}, {"value": '100', "perc": None, "unit": None}, np.nan]})

In [2794]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['E']])

In [2807]: df
Out[2807]: 
   A                                             D
   E                                             E
0  1  {'value': '126', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
1  2    {'value': 324, 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
2  3  {'value': 'N/A', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
3  4                                            {}
4  5  {'value': '100', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
5  6                                           NaN
```

I need to sort the multi-level column with index `(D,E)` in descending order based on `value` key from `dict`.

As you can see `value` key can have values in mixed datatypes like `int, string` or empty like `{}`, or `NaN`.

**`N/A` and `Nan` values should always appear at last after sorting(both asc and desc).**

**Expected output:**

```
In [2814]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,1,5,3,4,6], 'D':[{"value": 324, "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": '126', "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": '100', "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": 'N/A', "perc": None, "unit": None}, {},np.nan]})

In [2799]: df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['E']])

In [2811]: df1
Out[2811]: 
   A                                             D
   E                                             E
0  2    {'value': 324, 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
1  1  {'value': '126', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
2  5  {'value': '100', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
3  3  {'value': 'N/A', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
4  4                                            {}
5  6                                           NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper column filled by numeric and sorting by this column:

```
df['tmp'] = pd.to_numeric(df[('D','E')].str.get('value'), errors='coerce')
df1 = df.sort_values('tmp', ascending=False).drop('tmp', axis=1)
print (df1)
   A                                             D
   E                                             E
1  2    {'value': 324, 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
0  1  {'value': '126', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
4  5  {'value': '100', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
2  3  {'value': 'N/A', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
3  4                                            {}
5  6                                           NaN
```

---

```
df1 = df.sort_values('tmp').drop('tmp', axis=1)
print (df1)
   A                                             D
   E                                             E
4  5  {'value': '100', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
0  1  {'value': '126', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
1  2    {'value': 324, 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
2  3  {'value': 'N/A', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
3  4                                            {}
5  6                                           NaN
```