# Pandas: Sort multilevel column with mixed datatypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

This is an extension to this [`previous`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571500/pandas-sort-a-multiindex-dataframes-multi-level-column-with-mixed-datatypes) question of mine.

Below is the df:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b:all:c','all:1:3','c','d','e'], 'D':[{"value": '126', "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": 324, "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": 'N/A', "perc": None, "unit": None}, {}, {"value": '100', "perc": None, "unit":
    ...:  None}, np.nan]})
    ...: 
In [34]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['E']])

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
         A                                             D
         E                                             E
0        a  {'value': '126', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
1  b:all:c    {'value': 324, 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
2  all:1:3  {'value': 'N/A', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
3        c                                            {}
4        d  {'value': '100', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
5        e                                           NaN
```

I need to sort the multi-level column with index `(D,E)` in descending order based on value key from dict.

**But I need to leave the rows as it is that contain the substring `all` in all earlier columns.**

As you can see value key can have values in mixed datatypes like int, string or empty like {}, or NaN.

N/A and Nan values should always appear at last after sorting(both asc and desc).

So, the **expected output** will be:

```
In [38]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b:all:c','all:1:3','d','c','e'], 'D':[{"value": '126', "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": 324, "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": 'N/A', "perc": None, "unit": None}, {"value": '100', "perc": None, "unit": No
    ...: ne},{}, np.nan]})
    ...: 

In [40]: df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['E']])

In [41]: df1
Out[41]: 
         A                                             D
         E                                             E
0        a  {'value': '126', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
1  b:all:c    {'value': 324, 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
2  all:1:3  {'value': 'N/A', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
3        d  {'value': '100', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
4        c                                            {}
5        e                                           NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is find all rows with `all` before column `(D, E)` first to mask, then filter rows to `df1` which not match, sorting and extract index values used for mapping original index values and last sorting:

```
print (df)
mask = (df.iloc[:, : df.columns.get_loc(('D','E'))]
          .apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('all'))
          .any(axis=1))
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool

df1 = df[~mask].copy()
df1['tmp'] = pd.to_numeric(df1[('D','E')].str.get('value'), errors='coerce')
idx = df1.sort_values('tmp', ascending=False).index
print (idx)
Int64Index([0, 4, 3, 5], dtype='int64')

d = dict(zip(df.index[~mask], idx))
print (d)
{0: 0, 3: 4, 4: 3, 5: 5}

df = df.set_index(df.rename(d).index).sort_index()
print (df)
         A                                             D
         E                                             E
0        a  {'value': '126', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
1  b:all:c    {'value': 324, 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
2  all:1:3  {'value': 'N/A', 'perc': None, 'unit': None
3        d  {'value': '100', 'perc': None, 'unit': None}
4        c                                            {}
5        e                                           NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Will this solution work even if there were more columns with `all` substring? In that case we will need to avoid rows from all columns which have `all` as substring.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - So if all rows has `all` then no sort, right? Because sorting only for non `all` rows, right?

Comment: Yes. Let me add sample data for more clarification.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Sure, it is the best here.

Comment: Sample data is not required. I checked and your solution is working fine with other cases also.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Sorry, I forget ;) OOPs,